# is this info message any concern?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy the contents of one column in a table (which has only one col) to another table import.location. this works but at the completion there is this message

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Procedure Sp_generatelocation, Line 39
>   There is already an object named 'Location' in the database.

Why does this message came if I am not doing anything with Location but reading.

```
use [IBS]
go
INSERT INTO dbo.NewEdders 
(LOLCID)
SELECT location
FROM Import.location
```

Comment: Please tag which database engine you are using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...)

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the stored procedure? The error references line 39 and you've copied 6 lines (and if I'm not mistaken, the line count will start over after a `GO`).

Comment: You are not reading. You are trying to insert into dbo.NewEdders.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: this is the complete query. I was just wondering why that message came.

Comment: maybe you have a trigger or something getting fired that is calling the stored proc.. `Sp_generatelocation`